# SSRS - How to Pass Main Report Stored Procedure Data to Subreport Stored Procedure in RDLC

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

If the question seems silly, please take it easy on me. Still learning the breadth of SSRS and not sure if this has been asked before but to this point have not been able to find solid solutions...

Currently looking to generate a report that has a main/parent level DataSet that is generated by a TableAdapter that calls to a stored procedure and a subreport (also with data it would have to get from a stored procedure) based on the grouping of data that comes from that parent level report.

For example, we might have a top-level report that retrieves various manager-related items and groups them by ManagerID (theoretically giving a condensed list of unique manager IDs). For each manager (and their ID), they will have a subreport that shows the tasks related to them. But the caveat is that the subreports need to pull their stored procedure data based on the IDs obtained in this parent-level grouping; filtering of an initial set of subreport data cannot be used as the Manager IDs are not known prior to actually running the parent stored procedure.

This would be similar behaviour to Crystal Reports; subreports can be associated with stored procedures and have linked parameters from the parent reports. Using these parameters, the subreports are able to execute the stored procedure based on the parameter supplied at the group level.

**How would the subreport and its stored procedure DataSet be linked to the main parent using this grouped ManagerID column? Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

---

Currently Using:

- Visual Studio 2022 and Report Designer
- RDLC (With local processing)
- DataSet (.xsd) with TableAdapters for the Main Report SP and Subreport SP

---

From my understanding, the details for the DataSets are all filled (TableAdapter.Fill()) and attached to the report as a ReportDataSource with the filled DataTable before the report is generated/processed. This works when dealing with parent level reports or subreports that only filter data on the same table since the same DataSet can be sent to the subreport and filtered by a parameter sent from the parent.

Not entirely sure how to send that possible grouped ManagerID parameter to the subreport and have it get the data from a Stored Procedure on the fly. May just be over thinking this...

Comment: RDLC is HTML.  You can open the RDLC with a text editor to see the dat.  The SQL query is call Command_Text in the RDLC.  DataSet/DateTable are c# methods and are not recognized in HTML.  You need in HTML to take query results and put into table using HTML methods.  DataSet is not xsd.  XSD is an XML schema and is not HTML.  In c# you can fill a DataSet from an XML file using the ReadXml method.

Comment: If the report design is going to remain static, and you already have SP's to get the data, why not just build the report and subreport as a standard RDLs and this would be simple. MainSP gets list of, as yet, unknown ManagerIDs and produces a list of subreports, 1 per ManagerID. The subreport gets its data from another SP that takes the ManagerID as a parameter (typically)

Comment: @AlanSchofield due to the system design, RDLCs are required in this scenario. 

Based on what you are saying, is any of that behaviour able to be replicated using RDLCs or is there a key difference between RDLs and RDLCs as to why the scenario of generating the subreport (and SP data) with the parent ManagerID might/might not be possible.

Comment: I haven't used RDLC for reporting for many years so I can't really help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly surprised that this has not come up or been documented in many places given the number of years this has been around but my main way of solving this was to handle the retrieving of new data for each Subreport's Stored Procedure within the SubreportProcessingEventHandler of my SSRS class.

For example:

```
private void LoadSubreportDataSource(SubreportProcessingEventArgs e) {
    e.DataSources.Clear();

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); // the .xsd

    TableAdapter subreportTableTblAdapter = new TableAdapter(); // the subreport's TableAdapter in the DataSet

    // Filling the data based on the ID retrieved from the grouped Manager ID in the parent report tablix
    tblAdapter.Fill(
      dataSet.subreportTable, 
      e.Parameters["Manager_ID"].Values.FirstOrDefault()
    );

    ReportDataSource ds_subreport = new ReportDataSource(dataSet .subreportTable.TableName, (DataTable)dataSet.subreportTable);

    e.DataSources.Add(ds_subreport);
}
```

Cannot say if this is the most efficient method, however it seems to be working as expected: Each subreport will properly obtain the stored procedure data using the ID passed to it from the parent report after the Managers have been grouped by their IDs.

Still share any answers if there are cleaner, more concise ways to do this.